# Implementations for asm("nop") in windows

Tags: c, assembly, visual-c++, no-op

Is an empty line of code that ends with a semicolon equivelent to an asm("nop") instruction?

```
volatile int x = 5;

if(x == 5){
  printf("x has not been changed yet\n");
}
else{
  ;//Is this the same as asm("nop") or __asm nop in windows?
  //alternatively could use __asm nop or __nop();
}
```

I looked at this answer and it makes me not want to use an x86 specific implementation of using inline assembly.
[Is `__asm nop` the Windows equivalent of `asm volatile("nop");` from GCC compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878898/is-asm-nop-the-windows-equivalent-of-asm-volatilenop-from-gcc-compile)

I can use this void __nop(); function that msdn seems to recommend, but I don't want to drag in the  library if I don't have to.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/nop?view=vs-2017

Is there a cheap, portable way to add a nop instruction that won't get compiled out?  I thought an empty semicolon either was nop or compiled out but I can't find any info on it tonight for some reason.

*CLARIFICATION EDIT*  I can use inline asm to do this for x86 but I would like it to be portable.  I can use the windows  library __nop() but I don't want to import the library into my project, its undesirable overhead.

I am looking for a cleaver way to generate a NOP instruction that will not be optimized out (with standard C syntax preferably) that can be made into a MACRO and used throughout a project, having minimal overhead and works (or can easy be improved to work) on windows/linux/x86/x64.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cheap, portable way to add a nop instruction that wont get compiled out'? An empty statement is not the same as adding a `nop` instruction.

Comment: I mean i dont want to add a library just to force the compiler to add a NOP.  I also dont want to implement a NOP for only x86 incase this project gets moved to x64.  If the empty statement is not the same, is there another way to do it with standard C syntax?  Some clever trick that can be made an MACRO would be what im looking for.

Comment: x86-64 uses the same `nop` mnemonic and machine encoding as 32-bit x86.  `_emit 0x90` may work; maybe have a look at what Intel's IACA headers use to make `IACA_START` and `IACA_END` work on x64 MSVC?

Comment: You should really edit your question to say what you mean by "portable" so people aren't confused unless/until they don't read the comments.  I assumed you meant portable to other architectures (like ARM, AArch64, and PowerPC, all of which MSVC has supported or does support).  And/or to other compilers.  MSVC is the only compiler where portability between x86 and x86-64 is even a challenge, because its inline-asm is so bad that they removed it for x86-64.

Comment: I'm curious about why you want to inject NOP instructions,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I mean i don't want to add a library just to force the compiler to add a NOP.

... in a way that is independent of compiler settings (such as optimization settings) and in a way that works with all Visual C++ versions (and maybe even other compilers):

No chance: A compiler is free on how it is generating code as long as the assembler code has the behavior the C code is describing.

And because the `NOP` instruction does not change the behavior of the program, the compiler is free to add it or to leave it out.

Even if you found a way to force the compiler to generate a `NOP`: One update of the compiler or a Windows update modifying some file and the compiler might not generate the `NOP` instruction any longer.

> I can use inline asm to do this for x86 but I would like it to be portable.

As I wrote above, any way to force the compiler to write a `NOP` would only work on a certain compiler version for a certain CPU.

Using inline assembly or `__nop()` you might cover all compilers of a certain manufacturer (for example: all GNU C compilers or all variants of Visual C++ etc...).

Another question would be: Do you explicitly need the "official" `NOP` instruction or can you live with any instruction that does nothing?

If you could live with any instruction doing (nearly) nothing, reading a global or static `volatile` variable could be a replacement for `NOP`:

```
static volatile char dummy;
    ...
else
{
    (void)dummy;
}
```

This should force the compiler to add a `MOV` instruction reading the variable `dummy`.

Background:

If you wrote a device driver, you could link the variable `dummy` to some location where reading the variable has "side-effects". Example: **Reading** a variable located in VGA video memory can cause influence the screen content!

Using the `volatile` keyword you do not only tell the compiler that the value of the variable may change at any time, but also that reading the variable may have such effects.

This means that the compiler has to assume that not reading the variable causes the program not to work correctly. It cannot optimize away the (actually unnecessary) `MOV` instruction reading the variable.

Comment: Do mean a VGA I/O register?  Or do you literally mean in *video memory*?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I talk about the video memory range (0xA0000-0xAFFFF): In many 16-color modes, writing memory is done 8-bit-wise (from CPU point of view), but actually 32 bits are written. There are different operating modes of the VGA card. In most of these modes, 24 or even 28 bits written to the VGA memory depend on the last *read* operation from VGA memory, while only 8 or 4 of the 32 bits written depend on the byte written by the CPU. So performing a *read* operation will indirectly influence the video memory content by influencing the following *write* operation.

Comment: Ah, so the read has an indirect effect, not an immediate direct effect.  Neat, thanks.  Also, sounds like an interesting design choice...

Comment: @MartinRosenau Thank you for your answer.  I was looking for a useless/benign instruction that is mandatory-compiled with standard C syntax for multiple OS/compiler combinations, which did not necessarily HAVE to be a NOP.  Very cleaver, and cleaver application use with VGA.

Answer (score 3):

> Is an empty line of code that ends with a semicolon equivelent to an asm("nop") instruction?

No, of course not.  You could have trivially tried it yourself.  (On your own machine, or on the Godbolt compiler explorer, https://godbolt.org/)

You wouldn't want innocent CPP macros to introduce a NOP if `FOO(x);` expanded to just `;` because the appropriate definition for `FOO()` in this case was the empty string.

---

**`__nop()` is not a library function.  It's an *intrinsic* that does exactly what you want.**  e.g.

```
#ifdef USE_NOP

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <intrin.h>
#define NOP() __nop()       // _emit 0x90
#else
// assume __GNUC__ inline asm
#define NOP() asm("nop")    // implicitly volatile
#endif

#else
#define NOP()  // no NOPs
#endif

int idx(int *arr, int b) {
    NOP();
    return arr[b];
}
```

compiles with Clang7.0 -O3 for x86-64 Linux to this asm

```
idx(int*, int):
    nop
    movsxd  rax, esi                     # sign extend b
    mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi + 4*rax]
    ret
```

compiles with 32-bit x86 MSVC 19.16 -O2 -Gv to this asm

```
int idx(int *,int) PROC                                    ; idx, COMDAT
    npad    1                           ; pad with a 1 byte NOP
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [ecx+edx*4]  ; __vectorcall arg regs
    ret     0
```

and compiles with x64 MSVC 19.16 -O2 -Gv to this asm **([Godbolt for all of them](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23ifdef+USE_NOP%0A%0A%23ifdef+_MSC_VER%0A%23include+%3Cintrin.h%3E%0A%23define+NOP()+__nop()+++++++//_emit+0x90%0A%23else%0A%23define+NOP()+asm(%22nop%22)++//+implicitly+volatile%0A%23endif%0A%0A%23else%0A%23define+NOP()++//+no+NOPs%0A%23endif%0A%0Aint+sink%3B%0A%0Aint+foo(int+a,+int+b)+%7B%0A++++NOP()%3B%0A++++sink+%3D+1%3B%0A++++//a%5E%3Db%3B%0A++++return+a%2Bb%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+bar(int+a,+int+b)+%7B%0A++++NOP()%3B%0A++++return+a%2Bb%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+idx(int+*arr,+int+b)+%7B%0A++++NOP()%3B%0A++++return+arr%5Bb%5D%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:29.782167077725127,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_16_x64,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.2899450879999999,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:'167')),options:'-O2+-Gv+-DUSE_NOP',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x64+msvc+v19.16+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%234)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:32.99705869722305,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang700,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.2899450879999999,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:'167')),options:'-O2+-Gv+-DUSE_NOP',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+7.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:32.99705869722305,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_16_x86,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:1.2899450879999999,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:boost,ver:'167')),options:'-O2+-Gv+-DUSE_NOP',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86+msvc+v19.16+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:37.22077422505184,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4))**:

```
int idx(int *,int) PROC                             ; idx, COMDAT
    movsxd  rax, edx
    npad    1                           ; pad with a 1 byte NOP
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rcx+rax*4]  ; x64 __vectorcall arg regs
    ret     0
```

Interestingly, the sign-extension of `b` to 64-bit is done before the NOP.  Apparently x64 MSVC requires (by default) that functions start with at least a 2-byte or longer instruction (after the prologue of 1-byte `push` instructions, maybe?), so they support hot-patching with a `jmp rel8`.

---

**If you use this in a 1-instruction function, you get an `npad 2` (2 byte NOP) before the `npad 1`** from x64 MSVC:

```
int bar(int a, int b) {
    __nop();
    return a+b;
}
```

```
;; x64 MSVC 19.16
int bar(int,int) PROC                                  ; bar, COMDAT
    npad    2
    npad    1
    lea     eax, DWORD PTR [rcx+rdx]
    ret     0
```

I'm not sure how aggressively MSVC will reorder the NOP with respect to pure register instructions, but `a^=b;` after the `__nop()` will actually result in `xor     ecx, edx` *before* the NOP instruction.

But wrt. memory access, MSVC decides not to reorder anything to fill that 2-byte slot in this case.

```
int sink;
int foo(int a, int b) {
    __nop();
    sink = 1;
    //a^=b;
    return a+b;
}
```

```
;; MSVC 19.16 -O2
int foo(int,int) PROC                                  ; foo, COMDAT
    npad    2
    npad    1
    lea     eax, DWORD PTR [rcx+rdx]
    mov     DWORD PTR int sink, 1             ; sink
    ret     0
```

It does the LEA first, but doesn't move it before the `__nop()`; seems like an obvious missed optimization, but then again if you're inserting `__nop()` instructions then optimization is clearly not the priority.

---

**If you compiled to a `.obj` or `.exe` and disassembled, you'd see a plain `0x90 nop`**.  But Godbolt doesn't support that for MSVC, only Linux compilers, unfortunately, so all I can do easily is copy the asm text output.

And as you'd expect, with the `__nop()` ifdefed out, the functions compile normally, to the same code but with no `npad` directive.

---

**The `nop` instruction will run as many times as the NOP() macro does in the C abstract machine.**  Ordering wrt. surrounding non-`volatile` memory accesses is not guaranteed by the optimizer, or wrt. calculations in registers.

If you want it to be a compile-time memory reordering barrier, for GNU C use asm("nop" ::: "memory");`.  For MSVC, that would have to be separate, I assume.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i always learn something when you respond to my questions.  I was not familiar with intrinsics and i was not aware of godbolt.org.  I could have tested the empty case, with godbolt i can test trivial questions in the future.

Comment: I cant @ you for some reason, hope you see this at some point

Comment: @Bwebb: commenting under a question or answer *always* notifies the user that posted it.  They don't show up in the tab-complete list for `@` if they haven't also commented.

Comment: @Bwebb: You could always test locally without Godbolt; MSVC comes with a debugger that can show disassembly when stopped at a breakpoint, or just compile and disassemble.

Comment: You are on wikipedia incase you didnt know, I just saw your name here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift

Comment: @Bwebb: neat; I added that text to cite my own SO answer along with improving the code block back in 2015, glad it survived later editors.